# Give 9 gifts to 5 users

Tags: excel

Ive created a game and in that game played 5 users which collected few points, Ive gived gifts manually but for next games how can i split or make in excel to calculate number of gifts,
[image: percent table]
this is ok using number format with 0 decimal places, 6+1+1+1 = 9

but in cases like this:

[image: percent table 2]
1+6+1+1+1 = 10, how can I make that only 9 gifts results?

Answer (score 1):

You should be comparing their percent (B2/SUM(B2:B6)) against each prize as it relates to the total prize (e.g. 1/9). Since you are comparing decimal numbers with another decimal number and expecting an integer (no. of prizes), you will be rounding either up or down depending on whether you are favoring a wider distribution of the prizes or favoring the top score.

Either way you are going to have to decide whether the lowest score should always receive a prize or if the highest score should benefit from the points awarded.

The three possible formulas to start with would be,

```
=MROUND(C2, 1/9)*9      ◄ closest to even distribution
=FLOOR(C2, 1/9)*9       ◄ favours wider prize distribution
=CEILING(C2, 1/9)*9     ◄ rewards highest awarded points
```

Fill down as necessary.

Now you have to either take the highest or lowest score and adjust that to compensate for rounding the division of decimal numbers to an integer. MROUND doesn't play well with SUMPRODUCT but these two may give you a solution that you can live with.

```
=FLOOR($C2, 1/9)*9-((SUMPRODUCT(FLOOR($C$2:$C$6, 1/9)*9)-9)*($C2=MAX($C$2:$C$6)))
=CEILING($C2, 1/9)*9-((SUMPRODUCT(CEILING($C$2:$C$6, 1/9)*9)-9)*($C2=MAX($C$2:$C$6)))
```

Fill down as necessary.

If the MROUND solution is best suited to your prize distribution model, use a *helper* column that can determine the MROUND returns and then adjust the high score according to the sum of the helper column without circular references.